# Multibinding WPF a propiedad de un elemento

Tags: wpf

Tengo una ventana de WPF con varios ToggleButton, quiero que solo este enabled si la propiedad de esa misma tabla prop1 (otro togglebutton) está activa y está enabled, además de si la propiedad toggle2 está activa. Con los dos primeros binding bien porque con poner el path ya coge el `IsChecked` por defecto, pero no se como acceder en el multibinding a la propiedad `IsEnabled` ya que siempre me devuelve UnsetValue para el converter aunque no este unset.

```
       <ToggleButton  Checked="myprop_Checked" Unchecked="myprop__Unchecked" x:Name="myprop" Margin="-20,0,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding myprop, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
          <ToggleButton.IsEnabled>
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource isEnabledConv}">
                      <Binding Path="prop1"/>
                      <Binding Path="toggle2"/>
                      <Binding Path="prop1" ElementName="IsEnabled"/>
                  </MultiBinding>
          </ToggleButton.IsEnabled>
```

Aclarar que esta dentro de un DataGridTemplateColumn que forma parte de un DataGrid vinculado a una lista del DataContext que es una lista de objetos de mi clase usuario con tipos simples.

Comment: IsEnabled no esta bindeado a VM?

Comment: @gbianchi no, IsEnabled es la propiedad del ToggleButton prop1. Podría hacer el binding a una propiedad a VM pero al estar dentro de un DataGrid no me hace el binding porque según he leído coge como DataContext la propia fila.

Comment: pero tu datagrid esta bindeada a algo.. por lo tanto esa prop no deberia estar bindeada tambien? ojo trato de buscar un contexto aca..

Comment: Mi ventana tiene puesto el this.datacontext = this dentro del code behind que actúa como VM, el datagrid tiene una lista que esta dentro del code behind que funciona perfectamente pero a la hora de hacer el multibinding dentro de una de las columnas al converter llega UnsetValue siempre.

Comment: y la prop isenabled de esa columna esta bindeada al vm o no? aunque sea con un converter? o sea como sabe esa columna si tiene que estar habilitada o no?

Comment: @gbianchi es que como es también columna no se como bindearlo al VM y por ahora la tengo puesta a true siempre